# AngularJS: Hide li element when it's clicked

Tags: angularjs

I have a html code:

```
<div class="col-xs-6">
  <ul class="list-group itemList">
    <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="(id, product) in drinks" ng-click="addToShoppingList(id)">
  <strong>{{ product.name }}</strong> - {{ product.price | currency }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And  the Angular code:

```
$scope.addToShoppingList = function(id){

};
```

I just want the  `id` element to disappear (hide, fadeOut etc), when it's clicked. I bet it's something about the `ng-hide` but for now I'm too dumby for that.

Thanks for any answers.

**Edit**: It should be inside the addToShoppingList function.

**Edit2**: This is the whole function:

```
$scope.addToShoppingList = function(id){
   $scope.itemsToBuy.push($scope.drinks[id]);
};
```

When the `li` element is clicked, it pushes that element to the new array. And then it should be hidden.

**Edit3**: If I want to cancel it and make the items come back to the array, the result is strange.[image]

Comment: you can have a property that you test against on each of your `drinks` or you can simply remove that item from `drinks` when it is clicked. There are a bunch of different ways to do this.

Comment: @Ronnie If you don't really want to waste your time for writing a whole answer, just head me in the right direction

Comment: Agree with Ronnie - It would be helpful to see some of the rest of your code.  Can you manipulate the drinks object towards this end?  What else is happening in addToShoppingList that might be able to be leveraged?  Otherwise you'll want to make a dummy object to reference if it needs to be handled separately.

Comment: This is about helping people not spoon feeding you answers with something you can easily google...later

Comment: @anied Edited my post, check it out.

Comment: @Ronnie I did. But somehow it doesn't work in this specific case such as mine.

Comment: you're halfway there in your `$scope.addToShoppingList` function...now remove that item from the drinks array

Comment: @Ronnie check it out. Added a gif.

Comment: you need to use ng-if, as you are hiding and showing... the click on li should remove and it should also work on vice-versa when you splice out... did my answer help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl2">
    <h2>Hide each LI:</h2>
    <ul>
        <li ng-click="pushItem(suggestion)" ng-repeat="suggestion in results" ng-click="visible = false">
            {{suggestion}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Below is the angular code:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl2($scope) {
    $scope.results = [1, 2, 3, 4];

    $scope.itemsToBuy = [];
    $scope.pushItem = function(item){
       $scope.itemsToBuy.push(item);
       $scope.results.splice($scope.results.indexOf(item),1);
    }
}
```

JS Fiddle on the same:
http://jsfiddle.net/59gdo817/

On the vice-versa, just `add the item back to results array` to show the li back.

Comment: When I'm implementing it into my code, everything disappears, but no errors are being displayed.

Comment: Do you have any solutions for it? Please:)

Comment: Can you produce a fiddle?

Comment: It's problematic to share a fiddle coz its angular... affz :(

Comment: Let me see, if i get a solution.. working on a similar fiddle.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I was making a working jsfiddle for u. https://jsfiddle.net/scgsc7or/

Comment: Here is your fiddle... with the fix... https://jsfiddle.net/scgsc7or/1/

Comment: Can you include that code into my jsfiddle? I'm working on it since 15 minutes and still doesn't work...

Comment: Ahh, thank you, my friend. But when I cancel it, it goes to the end of the array, not in the same place as it was originally. Is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a new status to the `$scope.drinks` array called `isHidden` which will track whether or not the item is hidden.  When the user clicks on that `li`, the function will set `isHidden` to true and the `ng-hide` will immediately cause it to hide from the DOM.

```
<div class="col-xs-6">
  <ul class="list-group itemList">
    <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="(id, product) in drinks" ng-click="addToShoppingList(id)" ng-hide="product.isHidden===true">
  <strong>{{ product.name }}</strong> - {{ product.price | currency }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

$scope.addToShoppingList = function(id){
   $scope.itemsToBuy.push($scope.drinks[id]);
   $scope.drinks[id].isHidden = true;
};
```

Comment: What if I wan't to cancel it? I mean, to make tchem visible again?

Comment: `$scope.drinks[id].isHidden = false;` ?

Comment: @Ronnie Tried it already, but the result is pretty weird. If I don't do it in a right order (from first entry to last) it will not work.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
    <div class="col-xs-6">
  <ul class="list-group itemList">
    <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="(id, product) in drinks" ng-click="addToShoppingList(id);" ng-hide='product.hidden'>
  <strong>{{ product.name }}</strong> - {{ product.price | currency }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And in your `addToShoppingList`, you can set the product to hidden:

```
$scope.addToShoppingList = function(id){
   $scope.itemsToBuy.push($scope.drinks[id]);
   $scope.drinks[id].hidden = true;
};
```